# Is a pop fly in foul territory, missed with contact and lands in foul territory fair or foul?

Tags: baseball

If a baseball player attempts to catch a pop fly ball in foul territory (regardless of him standing near or far from the foul line), misses the ball but it touches his glove and then lands in foul territory, is it ruled a foul ball or fair/live ball?

This is a simple but frustrating question that seems to have no answer only complete turn around once you get halfway through an answer that looks like it's answering this just to flip back to  where it bounces back into fair or player in fair territory and drops in foul territory.

The player is in foul territory trying to catch a foul fly ball that has only so far been contacted by the baseball bat but unfortunately misses the catch which in turn the ball bounces off his glove and still continues to land in the foul territory.

Answer (score 0):

The official rules only define a fair ball:

> A FAIR BALL is a batted ball that settles on fair ground between home
> and first base, or between home and third base, or that is on or over
> fair territory when bounding to the outfield past first or third base,
> or that touches first, second or third base, or that first falls on
> fair territory on or beyond first base or third base, or that, while
> on or over fair territory touches the person of an umpire or player,
> or that, while over fair terri- tory, passes out of the playing field
> in flight.

> A fair fly shall be judged according to the relative
> position of the ball and the foul line, including the foul pole, and
> not as to whether the fielder is on fair or foul territory at the time
> he touches the ball.

Any other ball would be foul.

The ball in your question is foul as long as it is not over fair territory when the player (who can be standing in fair or foul territory) touches it.